# Libreoffice cell/axis format: Insert a newline?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

The goal is to plot a value against date/time in the format `DD/MM HH:MM` but to have the time and date on separate lines.  I'm currently using source formatting but this isn't necessary.  A couple of naive guesses that don't work:

- Entering `DD/MM\nHH:MM`
- Entering `DD/MM_HH:MM`, highlighting the `_` and pressing `<ctrl>+<enter>`, as you would in editing a cell.

Here's the current situation:

[image: What I've got]

and here's what I'd like:

[image: What I want]

**EDIT:** This appears to be very date/time specific, in that date/time values aren't broken using the usual approaches for text.

Yesterday I had a helpful answer that should have worked but didn't.  The "break" option in the Axis Labels dialog box should have done the trick but appears to be ignored on date axes.  The labels also jump to 45° if set to 0°, no overlap with a spacing that would make them overlap.  The dialog box below shows the settings used to draw the graph next to it.

[image: Graph and settings that made it]

**Edit 2:** It further seems that this is specific to scatter plots (I don't have equally-spaced x values), in that a workaround for other (e.g. line) plots is to use text x values.

Comment: Given the behaviour discussed in my edit I'm inclined to call this a bug: The 0° setting is ignored if the labels would overlap, even if break is set, and try as I might I can't get `DD/MM␣HH:MM` or any other any date[space]time format to break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has now been logged as [bug 93030](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=93030) in LibreOffice (now status=
confirmed).

So there's no current way of doing this.

Update October 2017: still a problem, still logged as a bug

Answer (score 1):

A workaround might be to convert your date/time values to text, and use the text column as the data source for your chart.  I wasn't able to find a GUI way to do this, but this StarBasic code copies actual dates from column A on sheet 1 and pastes text equivalents in column B of sheet 1 (only 6 rows, but you can change the 5 to however many rows you have):

```
Sub DatesToText

Dim oSheet As Object
Dim oCellA As Object
Dim s As String
Dim i As Integer

oSheet = ThisComponent.Sheets(0)

For i = 0 To 5
    oCellA = oSheet.getCellByPosition(0,i)
    s = oCellA.getString

    oCellB = oSheet.getCellByPosition(1,i)
    oCellB.setString(s)
Next        

End Sub
```

Comment: I'll test it (I can easily get the date/time data in as text because it's coming from csv), but I'm doubtful -- using text as a data source tends to force evenly-spaced data points, which I don't have.

Comment: As I thought, trying to plot a scatter graph (required because of non-even x-spacing) with text as the x data doesn't work.  I've tried importing the dates once to use as x-values (as decimals) and once to use as labels, but data labels seem to be ignored in scatter plots.  +1 because in a very similar case it would help, even though it doesn't work for my case (which is becoming very specialised).

Comment: @Chris H Ah, I hadn't considered the spacing problem (which I should have since there's another open question on that exact issue: [Text labels on axis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31614548/text-labels-on-axis/31659801)).  You might be able to add empty rows to space correctly, although at that point the workaround gets so cumbersome I'm not sure it would be worthwhile.

Comment: Actually in this case I *could* get close enough by inserting blank rows -- my non-equal spacing is in the form of missing data and I could round to the nearest minute with no problem.  In the general case of course this isn't great -- I've had to plot data against essentially arbitrary time steps in the past.  Thanks for both your help and that link.

Answer (score 1):

After some struggling I found that while I could not type a special character or "insert" one  I could paste one into the Format field box.

So I selected an empty cell and entered some text with a newline using Ctrl-Enter and then selected that newline and copied it with Ctrl-C.
Then I opened up the Axis Format dialog and pasted that newline using Ctrl-V.
It showed up like this:
[image: Format Field with Newline]

And looked like this in the chart:
[image: Chart View of Format with Newline]

Version: 6.4.5.2 Build ID: 1:6.4.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.1

Comment: This wasn't a solution when I asked the question - the fix implementing it was in response to my bug report and introduced in 2019 (6.2).  Using that fix is rather subtle, with no way to enter the newline directly in a formatting box